# sharepoint 2013 IE8 redirect 404 error

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer-8

Now we build a site with sharepoint 2013. Per our customer requirement, we need to support IE8. But my develop environment is IE11(in windows server 2008R2), so I decide to degrade my IE version.
In the beginning, I can use IE11 to access the website which I created in share point. But after my degrading operation, strange things happened: I enter the url in the IE8, it is loading... seems every thing is fine, I can see the background pictures be downloaded in the browser,but few seconds when it loading completes(I guess), it redirects to the 404 error page.(normal page flash to the 404 error page) And I tried to use Chrome to visit this site, every thing works.

I also set the IE security level to low, and trun off IE ESC(enhanced security configuration), it doesn't work.

BTW, the IE8 can access the url:    myMachineName/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SitePages/Home.aspx
So I guess I need to add or change some configurations in the website which I created in the sharepoint to fit IE8.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the compability mode from ie8?

Comment: Yes, I tried compatibility mode, it doesn't work

Comment: Can you provide an HTML snippet or a public site? Properbly there are restrictions by deteced zone.